# Is it possible to break up a functions.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress website, where the chosen shopping platform is WooCommerce.

I want to create a series of Template files, to be called within the `content-product-single.php` file, which contains Maths calculations.  For some reason, the Maths calculations only seems to work when placed in the `functions.php` rather than my assigned Template files.  It was suggested that the way in which I was using the `get_template_part` tags could be incorrect.  Here is the original code I was using:

```
<?php
    if (is_product_category('category-name')) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/template-a' );
    }
    elseif (is_single('product-slug')) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/template-b' );  
    }
    elseif (is_single('product-slug')) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/template-c' );   
    }
?>
```

If anyone notices any errors in my above code, then please do let me know as that could be the issue but for the time being, I think that my Maths coding may only work within a `functions` file.

For organisation purposes, is there a way I can create multiple `functions.php` files or would this be bad practice?  I have tried `functions-template-file-name.php` and placed this in the root of the theme but still the Maths does not work.

Comment: Can you show a short example of what `template-a.php` would be?

Comment: Thanks for your time with this.  I know its not the correct place to put the code but I have placed it in the HTML section here https://jsfiddle.net/5gtsL8k5/ Of course, the outcome displayed is not correct but should give you idea of the coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php) secondary files like this in your `functions.php` (files inside the subdirectory `inc`):

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/inc/shortcodes.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/inc/frontend.php';
```

On `functions.php` (and included files) you should only add hooks (filters and actions) and their respective function callbacks.

On the template files (and their `get_template_part`s) you leave the HTML and eventually some call to a function of your theme, like

```
<div class="results">
<?php my_get_results(); ?>
</div>
```

Where `my_get_results()` (in functions.php) would be something like:

```
function my_get_results(){
   $results = get_something();
   foreach($results as $r) {
        echo '<span>' . $r . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  At present, I am currently calling templates via <?php
if (is_product_category('product-category-name')) {
get_template_part( 'templates/template-a' ); 
} etc.  If I was to use your suggestion, how could I incorporate the 'new' function files into the above if condition?

Comment: Apologies for any misunderstanding.  Are you saying that your answer may not be the solution?  I am just looking to create multiple 'functions.php' files, and then call them in `content-product-single.php` as I have coding for Maths calculations that only seem to work in the current `functions.php` file.

Comment: I have updated my question, to show the original way I was using the `get_template_part`.  Can you see anything wrong as I certainly cannot.

Comment: Oh I see.  Basically, only the `functions.php` file accepts Hooks and Filters?  As an alternative to using the Hooks & Filters, via the `functions.php` file, could I remove the Hooks & Filters and simply enter the functions into the relevant page templates?  Or would I still experience an issue?  Regardless, thank you for your time with this question.

Comment: You can have some function inside a template but that's not very standard... Filters are required to be inside `functions.php`

Answer (score 1):

The function.php file is automatically loaded by Wordpress, but from there you can include any number of php files (in your case, your functionality or calculation code files) in it.

You may add files something like this:

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/template/template-a.php');
```

PHP scripts run relative to the current path, not to the path of their own file. Using **DIR** forces the template to happen relative to their own path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, @brasofilo just beat you to it. ;-)